# Vim function to show documentation (e.g. phpdoc) for a tag somewhere like in a preview window

Tags: php, vim, ctags

I haven't been able to find a plugin or script that to display the documentation for the function for a given tag.

Say I have the cursor over a function `foo`. The source code for `foo` is in another file that's not currently open, but has been scanned into the project's tags file. I would like to be able to call a function that would display the documentation for that function, which would be above the function declaration in phpdoc format.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it provides the feature you are looking for but there is a very exhaustive set of plugins for PHP called [VIP](https://github.com/tobyS/vip).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the phpcomplete.vim plugin so it parses the phpdoc. This means while your in autocomplete, the associated phpdoc will be shown with the function name and args on the top screen. This is not exactly what you would want since you need to type something to get the info and not just going over the methods name with cursor but you may find it helpful anyways.

Unfortunately, its only for methods for now. You will also need vim-python and exuberant tags (to generate class tags)